# how to write, read and rewrite in a .txt file with c++

Tags: c++, url-rewriting, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

i'm a student and i have to create a program and an inform about the use of the program, so ii has to, if the file doesn´t exist, create it; if it exist, read it and save the variable, then it has to increase their value if it meets specific conditions, finally the program has to rewrite the file with the new values, save, and close it. i made a code but it works bad, i dont know where is the mistake. help me please.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
int varAux1,varAux2,varAux3,varAux4;
int a;
int var1,var2,var3,var4;


ifstream archivoLectura;
archivoLectura.open("informeuso.txt");


    if (archivoLectura.fail())
    {
        ofstream archivoLectura;
        archivoLectura.open("informeuso.txt");

            archivoLectura<<"linea 1: "<<0<<"\n";
            archivoLectura<<"linea 2: "<<0<<"\n";
            archivoLectura<<"linea 3: "<<0<<"\n";
            archivoLectura<<"linea 4: "<<0<<"\n";

        archivoLectura.close();
        archivoLectura.open("informeuso.txt");

    }


    archivoLectura>>var1;
    archivoLectura>>var2;
    archivoLectura>>var3;
    archivoLectura>>var4;


    varAux1 = var1;
    varAux2 = var2;
    varAux3 = var3;
    varAux4 = var4;


archivoLectura.close();


cout<<"hola"<<endl;
cout<<"programa prueba"<<endl;
cout<<"enter value from 0 to 9"<<endl;
cout<<"a: ";
cin >> a;



if (a>0 && a <3)

{
    var1 = varAux1 + 1;
}
else if(a>2 && a <6)

{
    var2 = varAux2 + 1;

}
else if (a>5 && a<8)
{
    var3 = varAux3 +1;

}
else
{
    var4 = varAux4 + 1;
}


ofstream archivoEscritura;
archivoEscritura.open("informeuso.txt");

    archivoEscritura<<"line 1-2: "<<var1<<"\n";
    archivoEscritura<<"line 3-5: "<<var2<<"\n";
    archivoEscritura<<"line 6-7: "<<var3<<"\n";
    archivoEscritura<<"line other: "<<var4<<"\n";

archivoEscritura.close();

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tell us why it does not work

Comment: *"but it works bad"*  That is not a very detailed, precise description.   Can you provide any information??

Comment: @ChrisWard1000: I think the OP is hoping that _we_ can tell _them_ why it does not work. However it would be helpful if the OP were to tell us _how_ it does not work.

Comment: i say it doesn't work because it shows:
line 1-2: 2293512
line 3-5: 2293456
line 6-7: 4287201
line other: 0

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit You are absolutely correct. I put as much effort into my comment as OP did into his question.

Answer (score 0):

I see two different variables with exactly the same name, but different types, and different scopes.

Do you think this is a little confusing??

```
ifstream archivoLectura;

ofstream archivoLectura;
```

---

Following your code:

**Step 1:**

```
ifstream archivoLectura;
archivoLectura.open("informeuso.txt");  // This might fail, and you check for archivoLectura.fail()
```

**Step 2:**

```
archivoLectura>>var1;  // trying to read from the ifstream, which failed to open.
archivoLectura>>var2;  // The ofstream (which was opened successfully) has gone out of scope.
archivoLectura>>var3;
archivoLectura>>var4;
```

Here you are trying to read from a file that we know ***failed to open***.
That seems like a big problem to me.

Comment: Do you think this is the problem? (hint: no - should be a comment plz!)

Comment: @Lightness: Yes, I do think that is the problem.

Comment: Why? Name shadowing exists.

Comment: Simply [compile the OP's code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/083a1a9eac5570cc) to see that the problem is a _runtime_ problem.

Comment: I never claimed it was a compile-time problem.  I said that having two different variables with the same name creates opportunity for bugs.  I have updated my answer with more detailed explanation.

Comment: on step 1 i'm trying to create the file for being use after, i mean, if i have to run it on another pc, it have to create the file because it won't be there, but if it already exist , just have to read it and save the variable. that's why i made that

Comment: He's re-opening the ofstream `archivoLectura` expecting that to re-open the ifstream. That goes further than simply having the same name for two variables, which causes a compile error when invalid. Of course if he followed good sense then he _wouldn't_ have used the same name and then wouldn't have been able to let his misunderstanding cause this problem. :)

Comment: Thats kinda my point there.   Programmers who avoid confusing (although valid) constructs generally avoid more bugs.  Programmers who write confusing constructs write more bugs.  (eg. I think we agree)

Answer (score 0):

Check this .... I think that's the solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
int varAux1,varAux2,varAux3,varAux4;
int a;
int var1,var2,var3,var4;


fstream archivoLectura;
archivoLectura.open("informeuso.txt" , ios::in);


    if (archivoLectura.fail())
    {
            archivoLectura.open("informeuso.txt" , ios::out);
            archivoLectura<<0<<" ";
            archivoLectura<<0<<" ";
            archivoLectura<<0<<" ";
            archivoLectura<<0<<" ";      
            archivoLectura.close();
            archivoLectura.open("informeuso.txt" , ios::in);
    }






    archivoLectura>>var1;
    archivoLectura>>var2;
    archivoLectura>>var3;
    archivoLectura>>var4;
    cout<<var1<<var2<<var3<<var4;

    varAux1 = var1;
    varAux2 = var2;
    varAux3 = var3;
    varAux4 = var4;


archivoLectura.close();


cout<<"hola"<<endl;
cout<<"programa prueba"<<endl;
cout<<"enter value from 0 to 9"<<endl;
cout<<"a: ";
cin >> a;



if (a>0 && a <3)

{
    var1 = varAux1 + 1;
}
else if(a>2 && a <6)

{
    var2 = varAux2 + 1;

}
else if (a>5 && a<8)
{
    var3 = varAux3 +1;

}
else
{
    var4 = varAux4 + 1;
}


fstream archivoEscritura;
archivoEscritura.open("informeuso.txt" , ios::out);

    archivoEscritura<<var1<<" ";
    archivoEscritura<<var2<<" ";
    archivoEscritura<<var3<<" ";
    archivoEscritura<<var4<<" ";

archivoEscritura.close();

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```